# Route redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Upon login, I would like a user to be directed to

> example.com/me

and not

> example.com/users/$ID_NUMBER

I've added the following to my routes.rb

> match '/me',      to: 'users#show'

And the users_controller

> ```
> @user = current_user
> redirect_to me_url
> ```

However, I get redirection loops. I can call example.com/me without any problem, but I cannot go directly there during the login step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the url helpers in your `routes.rb`

```
match '/me' => 'users#show', :as => :me
```

The `:as => :me` part is what creates the `me_url` and `me_path` helpers.

[**Rails routing**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)